# setup vscode so python import finds modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

From my home directory, find .so files:

```
find . -iname '*.so' 2>/dev/null | grep freecad-
./freecad-build/Mod/Draft/DraftVecUtils.py
...
./freecad-build/lib/FreeCAD.so
...
```

workspace settings.json:

```
{
    //"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python"
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
}
```

workspace .env:

```
FREECAD_LIB=/home/mac/freecad-build/lib/
FREECAD_MOD=/home/mac/freecad-build/Mod/
PYTHONPATH=${FREECAD_MOD}:${FREECAD_LIB}:${PYTHONPATH}
```

(I tried this with and without the trailing '/' )

vscode python file:

```
import FreeCAD
...
import DraftVecUtils
```

Errors reported in vscode:

Unable to import 'FreeCAD'

Unable to import 'DraftVecUtils'

I have been unable to piece together what needs to be done to get vscode to find these modules. Works fine for python modules like math, itertools, etc.

Comment: I have the same problem but only with "DraftVecUtils". I have to use A2Plus, and somehow it needs DraftGui. but it can't find DraftVecUtils.

Comment: I ended up putting an entry for each module in the settings.json file in the python.analysis.extrapaths. Now the import is good, but all the instructions for auto complete seem to missing some magic sauce, can't get it to work.

Comment: have you managed to do it?

Comment: I have not found a way to get autocomplete to work.